# Cannot import name 'update_contenttypes

Tags: python, django

```
manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0.80

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "manage.py", line 60, in <module>

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line

    utility.execute()

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/apps.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .management import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'update_contenttypes'
```

Comment: Please add your question and minimal working code to reproduce the error.

Comment: please dont just paste error stacktrace. add some minimal description to the scenario.

Comment: It was previously deploy using docker, but right now I just deploy the files on the server. It was supposedly being executed using docker-compose build.yml build. But I want to move out from docker and directly place the file on server and run it and now it err.